# get to know VS. come to know

Tags: vocabulary

Would you please tell me if the following mean the same? if so, which one do native speakers use more?

> Get to know VS. come to know

I am sure there is some subtle difference between these.

I am confused a little bit, as my profs. has already told me the following:

> Providing your sentence has not agent, you could use get to know that is, some thing like the following, couldn't we?

I heard about it.

Comment: I guess `come to know` (something) and `get to know` (someone) are common uses. A native can suggest if otherwise

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(At least in the US):

**Get to know** means to take one's time, make an effort or take special steps to acquaint yourself or familiarize yourself with someone or something:

> I think she's interesting. I'd like to get to know her - her likes,
>   dislikes, beliefs, fears, hopes, etc.
>
> Don't you think you should get to know one another before you get
>   married?
>
> Get to know your body and check yourself frequently for any discolorations,
>   bumps, spots, etc. that weren't there before.
>
> New house? Get to know your neighborhood before you allow you children
>   to go out and play.

**Come to know** on the other hand means to come across information, receive information through happenstance, or eventually learn of something, and implies that there was a process involved:

> How did you come to know that he was a spy? (=what series of events
>   led you to this information?)
>
> Halfway through my research, I came to know that no such address ever
>   existed.
>
> How did you come to know your husband? (= what led up to your meeting
>   him for the first time?)
>
> This book will help you come to know God. (=through a process of
>   reading, introspection, prayer, bible study, etc. - a process that
>   will eventually lead to you knowing God).

The nuance of eventuality and process inherent in "come" can also be seen in the verbs: come to find, come to appreciate, come to the realization that, come to accept, etc.

Comment: Would it be OK to use 'know' alone in your examples?

Comment: "know" can be used instead of "get to know" in my examples, however it can't effectively replace "come to know" because it doesn't contain the process and eventuality factor.

Comment: Funny enough, I was going to write more or less what you wrote, but then I started thinking about it and contradicting myself, hahaha.

Comment: Thanks. would you explain the following more? and what is a good synonym for it?Come to know on the other hand means to come across information,

Comment: "come across" means to find or discover something by chance: "I was looking through the member list and I came across your name." Note that it's also used to mean "see" in the expression: You have the most beautiful teeth I've ever come across. (Especially if said by someone who sees a lot of teeth, i.e. a dentist, photographer, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between *GET to know* and *COME to know* is basically a matter of register: the version with *GET* is almost entirely restricted to colloquial registers and the version with *COME* is almost entirely restricted to formal registers.

In speech, JuliandotNut's distinction between the objects of the two expressions is also largely valid: we rarely speak of “getting to know” anything but people. But when knowledge of a “thing” or a fact or a subject is in play we do not ordinarily speak of “coming to know” it: in speech we generally use other expressions such as “get familiar with” or “find out” or simply “learn”.

Comment: Both are inchoactive, right?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Yes: they express entering into a state of knowledge.

Comment: In your info on aspect, you didn't meantion inchoactive as a lexical aspect. Is it classified in a different manner?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng (That's -ative, not -active). There are several dozen I didn't mention, because in English they have little or no influence on how verbs interact with other parts of a sentence.