# "to get to know" vs "to get/become acquainted with"

Tags: difference

I'm interested in the difference between "*to get to know*" and "*to get/become acquainted with*".
I only know that "*to get/become acquainted with*" is more formal than "*to get to know*". But I also want to know the semantic difference between them. For this reason I found some examples.

A-variants are from [ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/30617/82229).
B- and C-variants are mine.

**(1a)** *I think she's interesting. I'd like to **get to know** her - her likes, dislikes, beliefs, fears, hopes, etc*.
**(1b)** *I think she's interesting. I'd like to **get acquainted with** her - her likes, dislikes, beliefs, fears, hopes, etc*.

**(2a)** *Don't you think you should **get to know** one another before you get married*?
**(2b)** *Don't you think you should **get acquainted with** one another before you get married*?

**(3a)** ***Get to know** your body and check yourself frequently for any discolorations, bumps, spots, etc. that weren't there before*.
**(3b)** ***Get acquainted with** your body and check yourself frequently for any discolorations, bumps, spots, etc. that weren't there before*.

**(4a)** *How did you **come to know** your husband*? (= what led up to your meeting him for the first time?)
**(4b)** *How did you **get to know** your husband*? (= what led up to your meeting him for the first time?)
**(4c)** *How did you **get acquainted with** your husband*? (= what led up to your meeting him for the first time?)

I also wanted to create the same variants with "*to become acquainted with*" but then thought "*to become acquainted with*" is  equal to "*to get acquainted with*".

So the question is:
Are (1a)=(1b), (2a)=(2b), (3a)=(3b), (4b)=(4c)?

Comment: If you are acquainted with someone, you know them only slightly (maybe you know one another's names and exchange conventional greetings when you meet).  To get to know someone implies a closer level of familiarity. You would hardly speak of 'getting acquainted with' your own body, as though you hadn't met it before!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you create some sort of relationship when you do either of these two things (actual or figurative). The relationship you create when you **get acquainted** is not as in-depth, thorough or comprehensive as the relationship you create when you **get to know** someone or something.

You might **get acquainted** with someone before you go on a date, but you would **get to know** someone before you married them.

In the figurative sense, **getting acquainted** with your body would mean becoming familiar with it and how it works, while **getting to know** your body implies a much deeper understanding of when your body might be signaling to you that something is wrong.

Similarly, if a teacher tells you to **get acquainted** with some material, you might peruse the material to get a general understanding of what it says. If you're told to **get to know** the material, that usually means you need to read it and understand it well enough to take a quiz.